# React router ignoring slash in URL

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

React router renders both `Foo` and `FooBar` for the route `/foo/bar`

```
ReactDOM.render(
(<BrowserRouter> 
        <div>
                <Route path="/foo/bar" component={FooBar}/>
                <Route path="/foo" component={Foo}/>
        </div>
</BrowserRouter>)
, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Why on earth would it run both routes? I think this is insane.

How would I use nested routes (without `:/params` in case I want to do more than one nested route? Such as `/foo/bar/baz/whatever`?).

Would an answer to this question even make sense without mentioning which version I'm on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With React Router V4, you can use the **Switch** component to ensure only the first matched route is rendered:

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

...

<Switch>
  <Route path="/foo/bar" component={FooBar}/>
  <Route path="/foo" component={Foo}/>
</Switch>
```

You could also use the **exact** prop to ensure the **/foo** route is only matched when the url is **/foo** and not **/foo/bar**:

```
<Route path="/foo" exact component={Foo}/>
<Route path="/foo/bar" component={FooBar}/>
```

Comment: Switch doesn't work. Only `exact`. If `foo` is above `foo/bar`, going to `/foo/bar/` forces `/foo` to render only.